# having issue with constructor

Tags: java, constructor

This is my code.
In my main function, I already include a constructor.
I have multiple constructor in my Client Class

```
public class Client {
    private String name = "", username = "", ClientID = "", password = "";

    Client[] account = new Client[100];

    public Client() {

    }

    public Client(String name, String username) {
        // will have generated function for ClientID and also Password

        account[clientCount] = new Client();

        account[clientCount].setName(name);
        account[clientCount].setUsername(username);
        account[clientCount].setPassword(password);
        account[clientCount].setClientID(CID);
    }

    public Client(String name, String username, String password, String ClientID) {
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.ClientID = ClientID;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (selection == 1) {
            Client client = new Client(); // object created called "client"

            name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Account Status: Admin\n" + "Please Enter Client Name: ");

            username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Account Status: Admin\n" + "Please Enter Client Userame: ");

            Client CLIENT = new Client(name, username);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    CLIENT.account[Client.clientCount].getName() + "\n" + CLIENT.account[Client.clientCount].getUsername() + "\n"
                            + CLIENT.account[Client.clientCount].getPassword() + "\n" + CLIENT.account[Client.clientCount].getClientID());

        }

        if (selection == 2) {
            // at here, unable to access to CLIENT object, what can I do access
            // CLIENT object to here. Or copy the same object into the other new
            // object

            for (int i = 0; i <= Client.clientCount; i++) {
                System.out.println(CLIENT.account[i].getName());
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: And that issue is...?

Comment: I can't access the CLIENT object outside the " if(selection == 1) "

Comment: Come on guys, wtf? Re-word that Q and please, format the Answer as well. Sheesh.

Answer (score 3):

Just put `Client CLIENT = null;` before your if-blocks and then use `CLIENT = new Client(name,username);` inside the if. You can then use CLIENT outside your if, but it will be `null` if the code in the first if is not executed.

In fact your program has a design mistake, as `CLIENT` will always be `null` in the second if, because it will never be the case that the first and second if blocks are executed after eachother ;-) So you should rethink your problem.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I will think about it. :)